# Is "The good food keeps us healthy and adds pleasure to our lives." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> The good food keeps us healthy and adds pleasure to our lives.

I believe that the article "the" is incorrect, but why is it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. The question is a trivial matter of how to use the definite article and would be better answered on English Language Learners site.

Comment: It would help if you could give a context for this sentence.  Is it an answer to a question like "Please explain the difference between this group of food, which is good and that group of food, which is bad."?  Or is it the answer to a question like "What is the difference between good food and bad food?  Or is there some other context that would help me to understand your question?

Comment: I'm absolutely unsure why this is considered off topic.

Answer (score 16):

The sentence is grammatically correct, but may not mean quite what you intend.

Using the definite article implies that you are referring to a particular supply or type of food which has been previously mentioned.

If you mean 'good food in general', no article is required.

Answer (score 6):

If you are stating a truth that concerns food irrespectively of any particular case, that is if you consider that this is always true, then the use of the article is misleading; you should not use it. Here is the principle. ("*Food*" is a noncount noun.)

> (**CoGEL § 5.54**)  **The generic use of the zero article**  The generic use of zero article with both plural nouns and noncount nouns identifies the class considered as an UNDIFFERENTIATED WHOLE:
>
> - Cigarettes are bad for your health.
> - Hydrogen is lighter than oxygen.
> - Necessity is the mother of invention.
> - Research shows that it is the elderly who are the prime victims of
>   inflation.
> - Hunger and violence will continue to mark the future of mankind/
>   humanity.

*More examples*

- Food of one sort or another is necessary for animal life.
- Food is essentially what sustains your body and keep you strong; although air is also vital for that purpose it is not considered usually to be food.
- Good food without good drink to go along with it is not so great.

*Cases of the use of *food* when one is talking about a given part of the "undifferentiated whole"*.

- The food that you left in the refrigerator has a better taste than that you left out of it.
- They had eaten all the food but had something left to drink.
- Eat the food that is in your plate first, then you can help yourself to some more.
- The food was great, but the drinks not so great. (*The food at the party*)